# More detail about, and non-trivial output from, gcov -f

Tags: gcov

All the GNU gcov manual online at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov says about `gcov -f` option is:

> -f
>   --function-summaries Output summaries for each function in addition to the
>   file level summary.

Does anyone have more information, and maybe a non-trivial .gcov output file, from using this option, in order to demonstrate exactly what these "summaries for each function" look like?

I will also try to try it out, but I thought if someone is regularly using this option they could tell me more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it puts different data in the .gcov file, just in the output of gcov itself. `gcov -f` prints the name of each function called, its % of lines executed, and number of lines in the function. `gcov` without `-f` just shows a summary for the whole file.

Comment: Thanks. From the URL above, when it says, as I've read many times

     $ gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage tmp.c
     $ a.out
     $ gcov tmp.c
     90.00% of 10 source lines executed in file tmp.c
     Creating tmp.c.gcov.

I never paid much attention to that 90.00% ... line, but that's what you're saying would change to a more detailed result with the -f option. We'll try it.

Comment: If you want some really nice output similar to `gcov` look into `lcov` (http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) -- it produces nice HTML reports that will actually show some bar charts about coverage as well as highlighted source code.

Comment: Yes thanks we use lcov already. It was just the console output of gcov that I had ignored.